# Error on Objects and methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I just started with OOP on Javascript. I am new to programming world. Could you please help me on the following code? My text editor shows syntax error on 'else' block.

```
function Dog(name, breed, weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.bark = function () {
        if (this.weight > 25) alert(this.name + " says Woof")
    } else {
        alert(this.name + " says Poof");
    }
}

var fido = new Dog("Fido", "Mixed", 38);

fido.bark();
```

Comment: `fido bark()` –> `fido.bark();` and the syntax checker probably complains about the missing semicolon after the first alert.

Comment: Oh, you are missing an opening `{` after `if (...)`

Comment: semicolon is optional in JavaScript! http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function Dog(name, breed, weight){
this.name = name;
this.breed = breed;
this.weight = weight;
this.bark = function(){
        if (this.weight > 25){
           alert(this.name + " says Woof");
        }
        else {
          alert(this.name + " says Poof");
        }
    };
}

var fido = new Dog("Fido", "Mixed", 38);

fido.bark();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `{` after `if (this.weight > 25)` as well as a `.` between `fido` and `bark();`

```
function Dog(name, breed, weight){
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.bark = function(){
        if (this.weight > 25){
            alert(this.name + " says Woof")
        } else {
            alert(this.name + " says Poof");
        }
    }
}

var fido = new Dog("Fido", "Mixed", 38);
fido.bark();
```

1. You need proper indention to see stuff like this more easily.
2. I think your runtime complaint about the else, because it was outside the function and not "attached" to the if, because of the missing brackets.
3. Maybe JavaScript isn't the language to learn programming. Do you just play around to learn or do you try to get something done?

Comment: I need to learn jQuery within few days (I have day job. HTML/CSS till this date). So, I am trying to make some foundations on Javascript.

Comment: Dog should probably have a closing bracket as well.

Comment: @chhantyal: Maybe you should learn plain JavaScript first, then jQuery. To learn JavaScript, you may check these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+learn or just read and watch everything you can find from [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/)!

Comment: @Tim Thanks a lot. I just downloaded some video tutorials by Crockford. Ya..I am trying to make some foundations before jumping into jQuery. Thanks again for your advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this.weight > 25)
   alert(this.name + " says Woof")
}
else {
  alert(this.name + " says Poof");
}
```

your not opening the if {

Answer (score 1):

```
function Dog(name, breed, weight){
this.name = name;
this.breed = breed;
this.weight = weight;
this.bark = function(){
if (this.weight > 25){
alert(this.name + " says Woof")
}
else {
alert(this.name + " says Poof");
}
}
}

var fido = new Dog("Fido", "Mixed", 38);

fido bark();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.weight > 25)
   alert(this.name + " says Woof")
}
```

is where its gone wrong, you're missing a `{`. It should be:

```
if (this.weight > 25)
{
   alert(this.name + " says Woof")
}
```